# How to edit Facebook customer chat plugin prompt header text

Tags: facebook, plugins, header, chat, messenger

I have implemented the new Facebook Customer Chat plugin and i am struggling with the editing of the prompt text. I can't find any piece of documentation that instructs how to do so. It changes when a person is logged out of facebook.

I have tried:

- Everything on Facebook page settings
- ChangingFacebook javascript SDK locale

Docs here: [Customer Chat Plugin Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin)

[Screenshot of what i meant.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RoiL.jpg)

Any kind of help appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attributes that you want to set are "logged_in_greeting" and "logged_out_greeting".

All the customization options for the chat plug-in are described here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin#customization